# Incrementing integer variable inside a generate for loop

Tags: verilog

I am trying to run a `generate` loop in Verilog, and the error says:

> Primitive output connection must be a scalar net.

```
//verilog code for 32 bit counter using backward carry propogation with generate loop
module backgen(q,clk,t,en);

    output [31:0]q;
    input clk,t,en;
    wire [31:0]qb;
    integer p=0;
    tff t0(q[0],clk,t,en);
    tff t1(q[1],clk,q[0],en);
    and a0(qb[0],q[1],q[0]);

    genvar i,j;
    generate 

    for(i=2;i<4;i=i+1)begin;

    tff t2(q[i],clk,qb[p],en);
    assign p=p+1;
    and a1(qb[p],q[i],q[i-1]);

    for(j=i-2;j>=0;j=j-1)begin

    assign p=p+1;
    and a2(qb[p],qb[p-1],q[j]);
    end
    end
   endgenerate

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem with your code is that you make multiple assignments to the same signal `p`.  I think this is because you don't understand what the `generate` `for` loops are really doing.  If you unroll the loops, you would have the same statement several times:

```
assign p=p+1;
assign p=p+1;
assign p=p+1;
...
```

This is clearly not what you want to do.  The loops do not execute the `assign` statements in sequence, like in a software language.  They are all executed in parallel.

You should start over with a different approach.  Do not use `for` loops yet, and just place instances of your `tff` and `and` gates manually as you did for `t0`, `t1` and `a0`.

Comment: just to add, not only all 'assign' statements are executed in parallel, but also all your 'and' and 'ttf' statements. All statements in verilog are executed in parallel (except what is inside of procedural blocks).